# Remove text after character (cut string sql)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I would like to cut left part of text when I will find character '#' :

Text:

```
1) 12341#123

2) 123#1
```

Correct Result:

```
1) 123

2) 1
```

Do you know how?

I try use this but does not work:

```
LEFT(A.Vat,CHARINDEX('#',A.Vat)-1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule:

```
select RIGHT(fieldName,len(fieldName) - patindex('%#%',fieldName))
```

Examples:

```
select RIGHT('12341#123',len('12341#123') - patindex('%#%','12341#123'))

select RIGHT('123#1',len('123#1') - patindex('%#%','123#1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming always only 1 `#`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(f, CHARINDEX('#', f) + 1, LEN(f))
```

For more than 1 `#`

```
SELECT RIGHT(f, CHARINDEX('#', REVERSE(f)) - 1)
```